# Knockout observableArray data binding not being updated

Tags: knockout.js

I have a very simple model set up where I have a list of email addresses stored in an observableArray.   These are editable via a `foreach` data binding, but the binding only seems to be one way.  When I change the value in the text box, the change is not reflected in the model.  However, if I update another field outside of the array, that update is triggering `foreach` binding update.

I have a fiddle demonstrating this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xeLcy/1/

And the relevant html is here

```
<div data-bind="foreach: addresses">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: $rawData.address, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeAddress">Remove</button>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Where the model is

```
var Model = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.modelName = ko.observable("modelName");
  self.maxCount = 4;
  self.addresses = ko.observableArray();

  self.addUser = function(email) {
    self.addresses.push({address: email});
  };

  self.removeAddress = function(email) {
     self.addresses.remove(email);
  };

  self.hasEmpty = ko.computed(function() {
      var hasBlank = false;
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.addresses(), function(item){     
         if (item.address === ""){
           hasBlank = true;
           return;
         }
      });
      return hasBlank;
  });

  self.allowAddMore = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.hasEmpty() === false && self.addresses.length <= self.maxCount;
  });

  self.addNew = function() {
    if (!self.hasEmpty()){
      self.addresses.push({address: ''});
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your address is not an observable. Change your `addUser` to :

```
self.addUser = function(email) {
    self.addresses.push({address: ko.observable(email)});
};
```

**See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/xeLcy/2/**

Comment: Thanks!  Knew I had to be missing something simple.